GraphQL - WHERE clause with a set of elements
How can we pass the values Dynamically in graphql from UIAPI similar to apex by storing the values in collection element  similar to the below apex in soql
Apex:

Set<String> Departments = new Set<String>{' Human Resources ', 'Information technology', 
            'Finance', 'Purchasing', ' staffing', 'Operations management'};


SELECT Name, Email, Department
                        FROM Contact 
                        WHERE Department =: Departments  

I have tried to store the values in a const and pass it to graphql
const research=[' Human Resources ', 'Information technology', 
            'Finance', 'Purchasing', ' staffing', 'Operations management']
                            
@wire(graphql, {
        query: gql`
            query searchContacts($searchKey: String!, $limit: Int = 5, $research :picklist) {
                uiapi {
                    query {
                        Contact(
                            where: { Name: { like: $searchKey } }
                            and: [
                      { Department: { eq: $research } }
                            first: $limit
                            orderBy: { Name: { order: ASC } }
                        ) ]{
                            edges {
                                node {
                                    Id
                                    Name {
                                        value
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `,
        variables: '$variables'
    })
    contacts;

I need to use the data binding variables and fetch the values reactively similar to the apex
I have tried to use the constant variables to store it and fetch but the graphql doesn't recognise it
Can we pass the values into graphql?

We can use a inkeyword and pass the values to graphql but is this a right approcah

Yes, the in operator is the right approach. Your SOQL example is incorrect, it needs an IN as well.

The Soql query is from apex class and the apex class we store it in the instance name and display using data binding i am looking if there is any approach in graphql as well

TIL that IN and = for list bindings in SOQL are equivalent. Wonders never cease.

When passing a collection of values the variable type must be of type array.
Standard Department field on Contact is of type String (not picklist), so the syntax must be like this:
$research :[String]
If a picklist field was needed, then the syntax would have been like this:
$research :[Picklist]
More info about Field Operators in GraphQL
As mentioned by others in the comments, IN operator must be used for the department filter (compared to apex which accepts both IN and equal operator)
{Department: {in: $research }}
Using dynamic variables in graphQL usually needs a getter variables method to pass JS variables to the query in order to evaluate them correctly.
Here is a sample working version of the graphQL query:
    searchKey = '%a%';
    research = ["Human Resources", "Information technology", 
            "Finance", "Purchasing", "staffing", "Operations management"];

    get variables() {
        return {
            searchKey: this.searchKey,
            research : this.research
        }
    }


    @wire(graphql, {
        query: gql`query ($searchKey: String!, $limit: Int = 5, $research :[String]) {
    uiapi {
        query {
            Contact (
                first: $limit, 
                where: {and: [{Name: {like: $searchKey}}, 
                {Department: {in: $research }}]}, 
                orderBy: {Name: {order: ASC}}) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        Id
                        Name {
                            value
                        }
                        Department {
                            value
                        }
                    }
                }
                pageInfo {
                    endCursor
                    hasNextPage
                    hasPreviousPage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}`,
        variables: "$variables",
    })



